# kotlin: how to inherit from Spek class to have common fixture

Tags: testing, kotlin, spek

I want to have a common fixture for my tests:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
abstract class BaseSpek: Spek({

    beforeGroup {println("before")}

    afterGroup {println("after")}
})
```

and now I want to use that spec:

```
class MySpek: BaseSpek({
    it("should xxx") {}
})
```

but i got compilation error due to no-arg `BaseSpek` constructor. what's the correct way of achieving what i need?

Comment: Can you please post the full error in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an extension on `Spec` that sets up the desired fixture and then apply it in your `Spek`s as follows:

```
fun Spec.setUpFixture() {
    beforeEachTest { println("before") }
    afterEachTest { println("after") }
}

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class MySpek : Spek({
    setUpFixture()
    it("should xxx") { println("xxx") }
})
```

Though this is not exactly what you asked, it still allows flexible code reuse.

---

**UPD**: This is a working option with `Spek`s inheritance:

```
open class BaseSpek(spec: Spec.() -> Unit) : Spek({
    beforeEachTest { println("before") }
    afterEachTest { println("after") }
    spec()
})

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class MySpek : BaseSpek({
    it("should xxx") { println("xxx") }
})
```

Basically, do do this, you invert the inheritance direction, so that the child `MySpek` passes its setup in the form of `Spec.() -> Unit` to the parent `BaseSpek`, which adds the setup to what it passes to `Spek`.

Comment: Updated the answer, added a working option with inheritance.